# How to raise an exception to exit Synapse Apache Spark notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I am attempting to carry out two actions in the event of a failure scenario.

1. Write the results of a table to a single file in parquet.
2. Exit a the notebook.

Take action based on the results

```py
if validation_result["success"]:
    print("Successful")
else:
    (
        spark.sql("Select * from notify_error")
        .coalesce(1)
        .write.format("delta")
        .mode("overwrite")
        .save(lakePath)
    )
```

As you can see from the above, I'm trying to create a single table using `coalesce(1)`.
To exit a notebook in Synapse I believe the code is:

```py
mssparkutils.notebook.exit(returnValue)
```

But I'm not where to place the code in my code above.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just do `raise` with `ValueError`, eg

```
%%pyspark

notebookName = mssparkutils.runtime.context.get('notebookname')
errorString = f"error in notebook '{notebookName}'"

raiseError = True

if raiseError:
  raise ValueError(errorString)
```

Comment: wBob, thanks for getting back. I really don't understand, how to relate your code to my requirement

Comment: I was thinking raising the error would cause the notebook to exit but maybe I’ve misunderstood.  See what the others have got to say.

Comment: Hi wBob, the chances are if you misunderstood then probably others here will have misunderstood. Basically, I need two things to happen if ```if validation_result["success"]:```  1. Save data to the 'lakepath'. 2. exit the notebook. I believe the code to exit the notebook is ```mssparkutils.notebook.exit()``` When I enter ```mssparkutils.notebook.exit()``` the code asks for a positional argument

Comment: Bob, I tweked your suggested code and made it work. Thanks

Comment: Oh, good news, thanks for confirming.  Feel free to just upvote my answer and provide your own answer and mark it as the answer if you think it's a more accurate reflection of your solution, or even edit it - I don't mind!

Comment: Hi wBob, not sure how to do a upvote